# Setting the menu in tiles (Wordpress, html, php, bootstrap 4, flex)

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I would like to make a menu in such a way that each item in the menu would be a separate tile [look attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUa7P.jpg)

It's possible? I have already code:

```
 <?php 

  $my_menu = array( 
  'menu' => 'menu-oferta',
  'container' => 'padding-offer',
  'items_wrap' => '%3$s'

  );

  wp_nav_menu( $my_menu );

?>
```

thanks to this I was able to generate such a code:

```
<li> 
<a href=""> link 1 </a>
</li>

<li> 
<a href=""> link 2 </a>
</li>

<li> 
<a href=""> link 3 </a>
</li>

<li> 
<a href=""> link 4 </a>
</li>
```

but the problem is that these tiles connect with each other and I can't separate them using PADDING. That's why I want my menu to look like this:

```
<div class="my-class">
 <li> 
   <a href=""> link 1 </a>
  </li>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
     <li> 
       <a href=""> link 2 </a>
      </li>
    </div>

<div class="my-class">
     <li> 
       <a href=""> link 3 </a>
      </li>
    </div>

<div class="my-class">
     <li> 
       <a href=""> link 4 </a>
      </li>
    </div>
```

what should I change so that my HTML will be generated in this way? please help. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use before and after property of wp_nav_menu, here is the updated code

```
<?php 
$my_menu = array( 
    'menu' => 'menu-oferta',
    'container' => 'padding-offer',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'before' => '<div class="my-class">',
    'after' => '</div>'
);
wp_nav_menu( $my_menu );
```

?>

So your code will look like,

```
<li> 
    <div class="my-class">
        <a href=""> link 1 </a>
    </div>
</li>
<li> 
    <div class="my-class">
        <a href=""> link 2 </a>
    </div>
</li>
<li> 
    <div class="my-class">
        <a href=""> link 3 </a>
    </div>
</li>
<li> 
    <div class="my-class">
        <a href=""> link 4 </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

then you can easily add background to "my-class".